# How to represent complex vector?

Tags: python, vector

I have a spatial (that is, 3D) map that I am planning on generating. The overall map is broken down into the following terms and sizes:

*NOTE:* Hektum is a made up word instead of using Quadrant since Quadrant denotes quarters. Hektum, in this case, denotes *16ths*.

> **Universe** (128 x 128 x 128 Regions)
> **Region** (16 x 16 x 16 Sectors)
> **Sector** (4 x 4 x 4 Hektums)
> **Hektum** (64.0 x 64.0 x 64.0 Vectors)
> **Vector3** (float(x), float(z), float(y))

My problem is determining a type that represents a `spatial_vector` - specifically when it comes to a `Vector3(float, float, float)`. Say I want to represent a location, supplying a `Vector3` is meaningless. A complete location includes something like the following:

```
spatial_loc = SpatialVector(`1976984.2197.44.0.4532.36.001.17.9027`)
```

where the parts separated by periods are:

Region (x:24,z:85,y:120) = 1976984
Sector (x:5,z:9,y:8) = 2197
Hektum (x:0,z:3,y:2) = 44
... *then everything that follows*:
Vector (x:0.4532,z:36.001,y:17.9027) = ???

The problem is really two-fold (*but I'm okay w/ focusing on #1 and depending on answers asking for custom ctype help in another question*):

1. How can I represent the 4th part of the vector since it contains floats? The other parts are (x,z,y) coordinates converted to linear values.
2. Is it worth writing my own `ctype` so this can be treated as a value? In a way it would make sense to do so for mathematical purposes.

Ideally, as part of #2, the following questions are raised:

1. I've read the Python docs on writing new types. However, what are the steps to do so? i.e., using a different IDE (Intelli-J for ex.) and how to compile, etc.
2. A value (`struct`) type can be assigned as `v = 3`. Is it possible to be able to have similar assignment with a custom ctype? For instance:

   spatial_loc = `1976984.2197.44.0.4532.36.001.17.9027`

Again, problem #1 is my main issue: how can I represent a `Vector3(float, float, float)` in the simplest format.

Comment: Floats are a poor choice for your application, they're not evenly spaced in Cartesian space.  Far better to use a 3 x 32-bit integer values.  This has the added benefit of fitting much more neatly into your existing scheme.  In fact, why don't you just use 64-bit integers - bits 0-6 are Universe, 7-10 are Region, 11-12 are Hektum, something like that.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: I was just thinking about a bitarray and masking bits like you suggest. What about using Decimal(...) instead of float? The 'evenly spaced' concern is rather insignificant in respect to such a vast area isn't it?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: can you expand on your concerns with floats' uneven spacing in Cartesian space? Is it due to precision? I hear that numpy is the tool for floats but I'm having issues getting it installed on my Windows system.

Comment: Take a piece of paper, better make it a large one, and draw a line across it.  At a point of your choosing make a mark on the line and label it `0`.  At an arbitrary distance from the mark labelled `1` make a mark and label it `2`.  Mark the positions of `3,4,5,,...` at the appropriate places.  Now, with a very sharp pencil mark the positions of all the numbers which are exactly representable as 32-bit floating point numbers.  After a while you will find that there are as many between 1 and 2 as there are between 2 and 4 or between 4 and 8, and so on.

Comment: Okay, I get what you're saying then.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you a beginner that is looking at a too complex solution or a experienced programmer with performance problems.

I will suppose that will you is in the mid...

I would never look first at ctypes solutions.

First, I would create a Python class with functions to work with your representation issues, suchs as str and repr.

One simple representation that you can use are tuples or named tuples. They are immutable, though. Lists will be fine too, but I would use instance attributes 
for the class.

I would also look to solve all float vector problems with numpy and scipy. They are libraries for efficient math processing.

Sorry if you are beyond it.

Comment: Not concerned with performance issues at the moment. @HighPerformanceMark mentioned essentially using a bitarray and avoiding floats altogether.